# Combine 3 MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am a mysql newbie. I would like to combine the following 3 queries and  the result set into one, but no success. The differences between the queries are in the WHERE clause (kw_research.id_country=) and in the SELECT columns (global_value, local_value, us_local_value). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Query 1,

```
    SELECT
    dn_domains.sid,
    dn_domains.domain,
    dn_domains.tld,
    kw_keywords.id_keyword,
    kw_keywords.keyword_name,
    kw_research.id_research,
    dn_tlds.value,
    (kw_research.local_search * kw_research.aprx_cpc * '0.42' * dn_tlds.value * '12') AS global_value
    FROM
    (((dn_domains
    JOIN kw_keywords)
    JOIN kw_research)
    JOIN dn_tlds) ,
    co_domain_keyword
    WHERE
    dn_domains.sid = co_domain_keyword.id_domain AND
    kw_keywords.id_keyword = co_domain_keyword.id_keyword AND
    kw_keywords.id_keyword = kw_research.id_keyword AND
    dn_domains.tld = dn_tlds.tld AND
    kw_research.id_country = '1'
    ORDER BY
    dn_domains.sid ASC
```

Result:

```
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+
    | sid | domain                 | tld  | id_keyword | keyword_name        | id_research | value | global_value        |
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+
    |   4 | infodomain.info        | info |      13534 | info domain         |       27181 |  0.05 |   4864.859894050059 |
    |   5 | exampledomain.com      | com  |      28566 | example domain      |       28694 |     1 |   8.064000120162964 |
    |   6 | domainexample.com      | com  |      27433 | domain example      |       27503 |     1 |  14.112000210285185 |
    |   7 | officedomain.com       | com  |      27072 | office domain       |       27130 |     1 |   297.3600044310093 |
    |   8 | extractdomain.com      | com  |      27578 | extract domain      |       27680 |     1 |   6676.991976928712 |
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+
    5 rows in set
```

Query 2,

```
    SELECT
    dn_domains.sid,
    dn_domains.domain,
    dn_domains.tld,
    kw_keywords.id_keyword,
    kw_keywords.keyword_name,
    kw_research.id_research,
    dn_tlds.value,
    (kw_research.local_search * kw_research.aprx_cpc * '0.42' * dn_tlds.value * '12') AS local_value
    FROM
    (((dn_domains
    JOIN kw_keywords)
    JOIN kw_research)
    JOIN dn_tlds) ,
    co_domain_keyword
    WHERE
    dn_domains.sid = co_domain_keyword.id_domain AND
    kw_keywords.id_keyword = co_domain_keyword.id_keyword AND
    kw_keywords.id_keyword = kw_research.id_keyword AND
    dn_domains.tld = dn_tlds.tld AND
    kw_research.id_country = dn_tlds.country
    ORDER BY
    dn_domains.sid ASC
```

Result:

```
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------------+
    | sid | domain                 | tld  | id_keyword | keyword_name        | id_research | value | local_value        |
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------------+
    |   4 | infodomain.info        | info |      13534 | info domain         |       27181 |  0.05 |  4864.859894050059 |
    |   5 | exampledomain.com      | com  |      28566 | example domain      |       28694 |     1 |  8.064000120162964 |
    |   6 | domainexample.com      | com  |      27433 | domain example      |       27503 |     1 | 14.112000210285185 |
    |   7 | officedomain.com       | com  |      27072 | office domain       |       27130 |     1 |  297.3600044310093 |
    |   8 | extractdomain.com      | com  |      27578 | extract domain      |       27680 |     1 |  6676.991976928712 |
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+--------------------+
    5 rows in set
```

Query 3,

```
    SELECT
    dn_domains.sid,
    dn_domains.domain,
    dn_domains.tld,
    kw_keywords.id_keyword,
    kw_keywords.keyword_name,
    kw_research.id_research,
    dn_tlds.value,
    (kw_research.local_search * kw_research.aprx_cpc * '0.42' * dn_tlds.value * '12') AS us_local_value
    FROM
    (((dn_domains
    JOIN kw_keywords)
    JOIN kw_research)
    JOIN dn_tlds) ,
    co_domain_keyword
    WHERE
    dn_domains.sid = co_domain_keyword.id_domain AND
    kw_keywords.id_keyword = co_domain_keyword.id_keyword AND
    kw_keywords.id_keyword = kw_research.id_keyword AND
    dn_domains.tld = dn_tlds.tld AND
    kw_research.id_country = '220'
    ORDER BY
    dn_domains.sid ASC
```

Result:

```
    +-----+--------------------+------+------------+------------------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
    | sid | domain             | tld  | id_keyword | keyword_name     | id_research | value | us_local_value        |
    +-----+--------------------+------+------------+------------------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
    |   4 | infodomain.info    | info |      13534 | info domain      |       13535 |  0.05 |     1415.231969178199 |
    |  30 | domainhotspot.fr   | fr   |      13837 | domain hotspot   |       13838 |   0.1 |    3880.8000578284264 |
    |  72 | domainrecovery.net | net  |       2931 | domain recovery  |        2931 |   0.2 |     1761.177677000428 |
    |  75 | domainburner.co    | co   |      16893 | domain burner    |       16894 |   0.1 |    2286.1440437994006 |
    |  82 | domainrecorder.co  | co   |      16969 | domain recorder  |       16970 |   0.1 |    1344.6720444302562 |
    +-----+--------------------+------+------------+------------------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
    5 rows in set
```

But, I need the following result set:

```
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
    | sid | domain                 | tld  | id_keyword | keyword_name        | id_research | value | global_value           | local_value         | us_local_value        |
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
    |   4 | infodomain.info        | info |      13534 | info domain         |       27181 |  0.05 |     4864.859894050059 |   4864.859894050059 |     1415.231969178199 |
    |   5 | exampledomain.com      | com  |      28566 | example domain      |       28694 |     1 |     8.064000120162964 |   8.064000120162964 |                  NULL |
    |   6 | domainexample.com      | com  |      27433 | domain example      |       27503 |     1 |    14.112000210285185 |  14.112000210285185 |                  NULL |
    |   7 | officedomain.com       | com  |      27072 | office domain       |       27130 |     1 |     297.3600044310093 |   297.3600044310093 |                  NULL |
    |   8 | extractdomain.com      | com  |      27578 | extract domain      |       27680 |     1 |     6676.991976928712 |   6676.991976928712 |                  NULL |
    |  30 | domainhotspot.fr       | fr   |      13837 | domain hotspot      |       13838 |   0.1 |                  NULL |                NULL |    3880.8000578284264 |
    |  72 | domainrecovery.net     | net  |       2931 | domain recovery     |        2931 |   0.2 |                  NULL |                NULL |     1761.177677000428 |
    |  75 | domainburner.co        | co   |      16893 | domain burner       |       16894 |   0.1 |                  NULL |                NULL |    2286.1440437994006 |
    |  82 | domainrecorder.co      | co   |      16969 | domain recorder     |       16970 |   0.1 |                  NULL |                NULL |    1344.6720444302562 |
    +-----+------------------------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: _The only difference between the queries is in the WHERE clause (kw_research.id_country=)_ - I've just spotted that that's not true. The `SELECT` column list is different across all three.

Comment: halfer - Thank you for your comment, you are right. I modified my question.  Somnath Muluk - thanks for +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the queries with a `UNION` clause and write a top level `SELECT` with a `DISTINCT` something like this -

```
SELECT dn_domains.sid,
       dn_domains.domain,
       dn_domains.tld,
       kw_keywords.id_keyword,
       kw_keywords.keyword_name,
       kw_research.id_research,
       dn_tlds.value,
       CASE WHEN kw_research.id_country = '1' THEN
       (kw_research.local_search * kw_research.aprx_cpc * '0.42' * dn_tlds.value * '12') 
       ELSE NULL END AS global_value,
       (kw_research.local_search * kw_research.aprx_cpc * '0.42' * dn_tlds.value * '12') AS local_value,
       CASE WHEN kw_research.id_country = '220' THEN
       (kw_research.local_search * kw_research.aprx_cpc * '0.42' * dn_tlds.value * '12') 
       ELSE NULL END AS us_local_value
FROM (((dn_domains
        JOIN kw_keywords)
        JOIN kw_research)
        JOIN dn_tlds) ,
      co_domain_keyword
WHERE dn_domains.sid = co_domain_keyword.id_domain AND
      kw_keywords.id_keyword = co_domain_keyword.id_keyword AND
      kw_keywords.id_keyword = kw_research.id_keyword AND
      dn_domains.tld = dn_tlds.tld AND
      (kw_research.id_country IN (1, 220) OR kw_research.id_country = dn_tlds.country)
ORDER BY dn_domains.sid ASC
```

Comment: Assuming that no individual query will return duplicates (which must be true if `sid` is a primary key) then you don't need the `DISTINCT` - the `UNION` will do that for you.

Comment: With or without DISTINCT the result is the same, but unfortunately local_value and us_local_value are not showing in the result set.

Comment: added the required extra columns.

Comment: Thanks, Juniad. local_value and us_local_value are showing up, but all values (global_value, local_value,us_local_value) are in different rows, how can I combine them into one row?

Comment: @LaszloMolnar - I have modified the query and moved everything into 1 query. I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Juniad - thank you, great solution :) , but one problem still exists, the duplicated rows are showing up in the result set. :(

Comment: |   4 | infodomain.info        | info |      13534 | info domain         |       13535 |  0.05 | NULL               | NULL               | 1415.231969178199 |

Comment: |   4 | infodomain.info        | info |      13534 | info domain         |       27181 |  0.05 |  4864.859894050059 |  4864.859894050059 | NULL              |

Comment: @LaszloMolnar - The 2 rows that you have mentioned have different research_id. Still the 2 rows should be combined?

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is this:

```
(
    SELECT ... /* i.e. query 1 */
)
UNION (
    SELECT ... /* i.e. query 2 */
)
UNION (
    SELECT ... /* i.e. query 3 */
)
ORDER BY
    sid
```

Here's [a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e88f/2) you can play with.

In each query, remove the `ORDER BY` and just add it to the end, as above. This approach will remove any duplicate rows between the queries - if you *want* the dup rows, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Bear in mind this may be non-optimal - an analysis of your tables may show that writing it all as one query would be more efficient.

Comment: I got this error message: [Err] 1250 - Table 'dn_domains' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause - If I remove the ORDER clause: [Err] 1250 - Table 'dn_domains' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Comment: You can't order by `table.column` in this case - just ensure that all the _columns_ are correctly named in each sub-select, and then sort on that. So, as per my example, if you have a column called `sid`, you must order on `sid`, not on `dn_domains.sid`. (You need to be willing to use answers here as _clues_ to your end solution, since you're the only person that can debug your situation.)

Comment: That said - the initial `SELECT` in my answer was wrong - apologies. I've modified it, and will add an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, based on a re-read of your question - you just need some OR statements:

```
SELECT
dn_domains.sid,
dn_domains.domain,
dn_domains.tld,
kw_keywords.id_keyword,
kw_keywords.keyword_name,
kw_research.id_research,
dn_tlds.value,
(
    kw_research.local_search *
    kw_research.aprx_cpc * '0.42' *
    dn_tlds.value * '12'
) AS global_value
FROM
(((dn_domains
JOIN kw_keywords)
JOIN kw_research)
JOIN dn_tlds) ,
co_domain_keyword
WHERE
dn_domains.sid = co_domain_keyword.id_domain AND
kw_keywords.id_keyword = co_domain_keyword.id_keyword AND
kw_keywords.id_keyword = kw_research.id_keyword AND
dn_domains.tld = dn_tlds.tld AND
( /* Here's the new clause */
    kw_research.id_country IN (1, 220) OR
    kw_research.id_country = dn_tlds.country
)
ORDER BY
dn_domains.sid ASC
```

I am presuming that id_country is an integer, and so have converted the numeric literals from strings to numbers. I've also used `IN`, which is a bit faster that multiple `OR` statements.

Comment: Thanks, halfer. Your solution combines the WHERE clause, but it only returns the global_value. I need 3 different values (global_value, local_value,us_local_value) in 3 different columns in one row.

Comment: Yeah, this was based on the incorrect information in the question (about how the three queries differ). My other answer is correct.